# Get elements from a div within a form JS

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the input elements form a certain div inside a form , not from all divs?

I want to use JAVASCRIPT not JQUERY.

I tried to use like this `discountForm.oldDivIdName.elements[i].value.length`, but its not working.

UPDATE:

I have a form like this,

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <div id='div1'>
  <input type="text" id="id[]" />
 </div>
 <div id='div2'>
  <input type="text" id="id[]" />
 </div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Both text fields id are named the same and I want to get the value of the text field of div named div1 and not from div2, how can I do that.

Any help?

Comment: inherent HTML problem: two elements on the same page should never have the same `id`

Comment: The div is made with `document.createElement('div')` so text fields name is a loop like `txt[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input elements have `id`'s, you can do something like

```
var value = document.getElementById('div1').children[0].value;
```

where you have

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <div id="div1">
  <input type="text" id="id" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please look again my question, I want to get an element inside a div which is inside a form

Comment: Yes I know this, but I want to get it from a certain div, I updated my question

Comment: Does this certain `div` have an `id` attribute?

Comment: then I think maybe my answer would help

Comment: I see you didnt understand my question I updated again my question I hope you'll better understand it, thnx